# I need to make this function more efficient

Tags: c, performance, list

My current function is O(n) right now. It appends two list-type structures by taking the first list and reversing it, then putting it back onto the front of the second list. I don't see how I could append the two lists with the functions I currently have. Does anyone have any idea how I could make it O(1)?

My current thought is maybe I might have to make a completely different function.

The append function:

```
ilist iappend_destroy(ilist il1, ilist il2){
   if(il1 == NULL && il2 == NULL){
      free(il1);
      free(il2);
      return NULL;
   }else if(il1 == NULL){
      free(il1);
      return(il2);
   }else if(il2 == NULL){
      free(il2);
      return(il1);
   }else{

   ilist tmp = iempty();
   ilist clone = il1;

   while(il1 != NULL){
      tmp = icons_destroy(il1->first, tmp);
      il1 = il1->rest;
   }

   ilist tmpclone = tmp;

   while(tmp != NULL){
      il2 = icons_destroy(tmp->first, il2);
      tmp = tmp->rest;
   }

   idelete(tmpclone);
   idelete(clone);
   return il2;
   }
```

The icons function that is being used by the append function:

```
ilist icons_destroy(int in, ilist il){
   if (il == NULL) {
      ilist anewlist = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_ADT));
      anewlist->first = in;
      anewlist->rest = NULL;
      return (anewlist);
   } else {
      ilist previous = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_ADT));
      previous->first = il->first;
      previous->rest = il->rest;
      il->first = in;
      il->rest = previous;
      return il;
   }
}
```

Comment: Typically you would make the last element of the first list point to the first element of the second list.

Comment: The problem is that the ilist structure is made of two things: an integer which is the first element of a list, and another ilist or NULL. A pointer might not work because I can't access the last element of the list without going through the rest of the elements, requiring a loop that would make the function not O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the original list being appended is being destroyed, as seems to be the case in your code, you can append two lists in `O(1)` using the following algorithm:

```
lAend ----------------------------+
                                  V
listA -> item A1 -> item A2 -> item A3 -> null
listB -> item B1 -> item B2 -> item B3 -> null
                                  ^
lBend ----------------------------+
```

You need end-of-list pointers as well as start-of-list ones but the code to append `listB` to the end of `listA` is simply:

```
lAend->next = listB; lAend = lBend;
listB = null;        lBend = null;
```

After that, `listB` is empty and `listA` contains the combined list:

```
lAend ---------------------------------------+
listA -> item A1 -> item A2 -> item A3 --+   |
                                         |   |
                +------------------------+   |
                |                            V
                +--> item B1 -> item B2 -> item B3 -> null
listB -> null
lBend -> null
```

If you *don't* store the end pointer, `O(1)` is not possible, since you need to find the last element of the first list, a fundamentally `O(n)` operation.

Comment: I don't quite understand your algorithm diagram. Are you saying that I have to take the input lists, add a pointer at the end of the first list that points to the front of the second list?

Comment: I see, so I will have to into my code, make it so that all ilists have pointers as their last element? If I were to do that, if I need the empty list, would the pointer be equal to NULL?

Comment: No, I'm saying that, unless you _have_ such an end pointer, you can't do it in O(1). The end pointer simply removes the O(n) operation of finding the end of the first list. The idea is to simply change the next pointer in A from null to the first element in B (and empty B by setting its pointers to null).

Comment: You can go either way. You could totally ignore the end-list pointer if the start-list pointer was null, or you could set them both to null for an empty list. Note I'm not proposing moving the current start-list pointer to point at the end, I'm proposing the _addition_ of another pointer.

Comment: From what I understand from what you said, I have to have an end pointer, a separate part of the structure that points to the last element of the list. Then when I want to append another list, the pointer changes to the first element of the second list.

Also, the structure does not have a ->next. It only has ->first and ->rest.

Comment: `rest` (rest of the list) appears to be your `next` (next item in the list) equivalent. And, as for the first part of that comment, yes.